# How to construct logic deduction for this?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am new to logic and math exchange. I am taking a class that requires a deduction of these two logical premises and a conclusion. How do I use the laws of logic to deduce this conclusion?

$( \neg C \wedge S) \vee (\neg C \wedge D)$

$\neg ( S \vee A )$

$\therefore ( \neg C \wedge \neg S) \wedge \neg A$

Comment: There is  no such thing as "the laws of logic".  The are many logics, and many rulesets.

Comment: " I am taking a class" : if it's a mathematical logic class then I advise you to just sit down and run through a lot of exercises.  This type of formalism is best considered as; very structured symbol flipping.  Don't lean on interpretation; consider it a puzzle/game.  It's really not hard, just not intuitive in common culture.   For a mathematics logic class, I am sure there are a lot of exercises and examples.

Answer (score 1):

$$\neg ( S \vee A ) \implies \neg S \wedge \neg A$$
$$( \neg C \wedge S) \vee (\neg C \wedge D) \implies \neg C \wedge ( S \vee D ) \implies \neg C$$
Therefore
$$\neg C \wedge ( \neg S \wedge \neg A ) \implies ( \neg C \wedge \neg S) \wedge \neg A$$

Comment: Got it - would you mind helping me identify what laws are being used and where? Really trying to understand this concept.

Comment: All I use is the distributivity of negation and the OR operator

Comment: "Distributivity of negation" is not the best name for [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). (Admittedly, "De Morgan's law" is an uninformative name, but at least it's not misleading.)

Answer (score 1):

**By Natural Deduction**

Take the premises $(\neg C\wedge S)\vee(\neg C\wedge D)\,,\neg(S\vee A)$.

From the first premise conclude $\neg C$ by disjunctive elimination (proof by cases).

From the second premise conclude $\neg S$ by contradiction elimination (proof by contradiction).

From the second premise conclude $\neg A$ likewise.

Therefore demonstrating both premises entail $(\neg C\wedge \neg S)\wedge \neg A$ by two applications of conjunctive introduction.